# Error java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1036KB - react native on android 5.1

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I created an application that was tested and is in production on api 29 or android 10, when testing on api 21 which is lollipop, the application restarts, whose log error is this one below:

all error log generated:
https://pastebin.pl/view/6d4d5df3

````
2022-03-15 18:58:07.220 20373-20399/system_process E/AndroidRuntime: *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: android.display
    java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1036KB
        at android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable.<init>(ColorDrawable.java:45)
        at android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable.<init>(ColorDrawable.java:44)
        ....```
````